# How can I capture the gesture in a page view when I start flipping?

Tags: ios, ipad

In the page view when you flip the page to the middle of the turn sequence and don't release. [**See pic**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnYSD.png), 
when I release, I  could  capture the finish gesture by below delegate method:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray
*)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
```

But, how can I capture the gesture event when the paging animation start?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out

`-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers`

method of a UIPageViewControllerDelegate